# Python script to sum up rows when there are common identifiers on the same date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset with multiple columns across different months. I have two identifiers I use which are License and Location. This is a sample of what my data looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU8JU.png

I am in the midst of migrating my data and one of my sheet requires all the columns except for "Type" column. However, when I migrate over, I would have duplicate rows since there are repeated licenses and location. I want to sum up these repeated licenses and location at every month. This is my desired output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwIz2.png

My migration code so far is:

```
def migrate(df, template):
    inventory = df.copy()
    inventory = inventory[['License', 'Location', 'Date', 
                           'Quantity' 
                          ]]
```

What other scripts can I write to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `GroupBy` object using a list of the column names for which you want to keep all unique combinations (using `as_index` to retain them as columns instead of transforming them into indices). This object essentially stores the values in the remaining columns for each unique combination of the given ones. You can then aggregate these remaining values using a desired aggregation function--in your case, `sum`.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(["License", "Location", "Date"], as_index=False).agg(sum)
```

Here is the output for the first four rows of your input dataframe:

```
  License Location    Date        Type  Quantity
0     123       aa  1/1/16  abcdebcdef         4
1     456       bb  1/1/16       fffff         3
2     789       cc  1/1/16       ggggg         4
```

As you can see, all values in the "Type" and "Quantity" columns for matching "License", "Location" and "Date" entries have been combined using the summation function. For "Type", that means that the strings have been concatenated; I've just included that here as a consistency check. You can drop that column once you've verified that it has worked as planned.